# PCI scope for a Direct-Post e-commerce site (SAQ A-EP)

Tags: audit, pci-scope, e-commerce

An e-commerce site uses the Direct-Post method (see page 14 [PCI e-commerce security](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/best_practices_securing_ecommerce.pdf)).
Is the server for the e-commerce application and network it resides on in scope for PCI?  There are questions in the SAQ A-EP for servers and networking that appear to apply.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the document you've provided, emphasis mine:

> [When performing Direct Post] the payment form is provided by the
> merchant; **therefore, the merchant’s systems are in scope** for
> additional PCI DSS controls, which are necessary to protect the
> merchant website against malicious individuals changing the form and
> capturing cardholder data.

And [SAQ A-EP](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2-SAQ-A_EP-rev1_1.pdf) is applicable to Direct Post merchants:

> Your e-commerce website does not receive cardholder data but **controls
> how consumers, or their cardholder data, are redirected** to a PCI DSS
> validated third-party payment processor;

So, yes, your server that provides the checkout page is in-scope for PCI, even though the Direct Post sends card data directly to the payment processor.  You should fill out SAQ A-EP accordingly.